# SQL Reporting Services horizontal line above subtotal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How can I insert a horizontal line above each subtotal in SSRS-2008?

The issue seems to be that you can't have borders inside of a grouping column.  So, my line won't extend all the way to the left. In the report I'm trying to make in SSRS, the line cuts-off to the left of the Item column, doesn't show in the department column, because it's not yet the "end" of that group until after the subtotal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the Item Column and insert a column to the Left of the Item column. The new column will have a cell for every row, and can include the borders before or after the total rows. Move the Department field into this column, and then delete the column with the vertical grouping. Don't delete the group itself, just the column.

If you don't have a summary row for the group, this can be added by right clicking in one of the detail row cells, such as the one that contains your Item Name and select Insert Row -> Outside Group - Above.

The Department field should be placed in the cell in the summary row. (The icon for this summary row in the left margin of the tablix will not have the three horizontal lines. Those indicate a row will be repeated as part of the detail set.)

Comment: Thanks Jamie!  This gets me almost there.  Now the department is repeated on every row.  Any way to get it so that it only prints once per group?

Comment: Added to my answer. Your screen shot above made it look like you already had this row, but I forgot that's not a screenshot of your report.

Comment: You're a beast Jamie, thanks!!  Wish SO had a beer-bounty system, owe you one!